# SPDIF Input not working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, spdif

One of my motherboard has two SPDIF sockets. One input and one output. Under windows these work fine and I am able to achieve what I'm trying here.

I want to set Ubuntu up so it will play the Digital input out the Analogue output(normal headphone jack).

Under my input devices there is no digital options, and under configuration there is no option for Digital Stereo input

I only have options for Digital output and Analogue input, when really I want it the other way around.

Can anyone shed any light?

[image]
[image]

error when starting `gnome-alsamixer`:

[image]

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can report the problem as a bug

Comment: Did you solve your problem, because i have the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Pulseaudio can't enable/disable the S/PDIF ports, this has to be done from ALSA.
Install gnome-alsamixer and there you will see the specific options to enable and disable SP/DIF (or IEC 925 as they call it)

Comment: I have added an image of the error I get when starting `gnome-alsamixer` and this is the teminal O/P: `** (gnome-alsamixer:3200): WARNING **: gam_toggle_set_state (). No idea what to do for mixer element "IEC958 Playback Source"!` I have IEC958, IEC958 Output and IEC958 Playback Sourse enabled, but "Playback Source" is unselected when starting it up again (i.e terminal error)

Comment: It seems then that your driver is not recognizing the S/PDIF port. Try to find out what specific audiochipset you have and in what configuration. Visit [ http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Main ]

Comment: In case you have a Intel HDA soundchip then also check this: [ http://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Resolve_Problems_with_HDA-Intel_Sound_Cards ]